# Updating and saving dict in django with post requests

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to make a responsive tournament bracket with python/django and using $.post requests to update a tournament dict - which I pass to a 'bracket' template as a dictionary, render, then update by $.posting the passed in variable to a nother view, which updates, saves to server, then redirects to 'bracket' view.

I am just starting to make some progress, but having issues with reformatting of the bracket object.

**Little more detail**

The bracket is initialized in python (in my views.py) in a bracket view, but I am calling in the view a Tournament class that I got from [here](https://github.com/JonathanZwiebel/bracket-generator/blob/master/bracket.py).

the Tournament class takes a list of players and then generates a dictionary corresponding to the games with the method t.generate_bracket().

I kind of restructure this and then pass it into a bracket view for displaying - I display the restructured array in my template but also pass in the un-restructured one

I have little radio buttons that are bound to a $.post 'update_bracket' view. In the JS $.post, I send the array to the view, where I will call a t.play_game() method to update the bracket. Then - instead of a JSON or HTTP response and subsequent re-population of the bracket client side (which I am not good enough at frontend to do), I save the updated bracket to a JSONField on an employee model (extends the logged in user) and HTTPResponseRedirect to the initial 'bracket' view, where I have a check to see if the Employee has a bracket saved to them, then use that value saved to the JSONField as the new bracket dict to be displayed - instead of generating from scratch with t.generate_bracket()

Here are my bracket view, my update bracket view, the bracket.html with json $.post() to update_bracket and some of the Tournament and other classes I am utilizing

**Code**

*Initial bracket view*

```
@login_required#(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def bracket(request):
    '''

    :param request:
    :return:
    '''

    emp = Employee.objects.get(user = request.user)
    emp_bracket = emp.guess

    players = [p.id for p in Pet.objects.all()]
    t = Tournament(players)
    if not emp_bracket:
        t.generate_bracket('single', 0)
    else:
        t.games = emp_bracket
    tournament_games = t.games

    nested_tournament_games = {}
    nested_tournament_games['rounds']={}


    for g_id,g in tournament_games.items():
        #....I do restructuring of the tournament_games dict

    context = {'arr':tournament_games, 'nested':nested_tournament_games['rounds']}#{'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'madness/bracket.html', context)
```

*.post in bracket template*

```
$('input[type=radio][name=bStatus]').change(function() {
alert(this.value);

$.post('{% url "update_bracket"  %}',
        { bracketData: JSON.stringify("{{arr}}") },
        function(data, status, xhr) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
var nested = JSON.stringify(data);
        }).done(function() {  })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, ex) { alert('failed, ' + ex); });
});
```

*update_bracket view*

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_bracket(request):
    bracketData = request.POST['bracketData']
    print(json.loads(bracketData))

    #I plan on using the play_game() method here, but first I have to just get the basics down

    emp = Employee.objects.get(user = request.user)
    emp.guess = bracketData
    emp.save()
    # return HttpResponse(json.loads(bracketData))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bracket'))
```

*Tournament class I am using*

```
class Tournament:
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.players = players
        self.player_count = len(players)
        self.games = {}

...


    def generate_bracket(self, bracket_class, randomize):
        if bracket_class != "single":
            print("Illegal bracket class")
            quit()

        self.n_size = int(math.ceil(math.log(self.player_count, 2)))
        self.underflow = int(math.pow(2, self.n_size) - self.player_count)

        if randomize:
            random.shuffle(self.players)

        for i in range(self.underflow):
            self.players.append(None)

        self.num_of_rounds = int(math.log(len(self.players), 2))

        self.games = generate_bracket_rec(self.players, self.num_of_rounds)


...

def generate_bracket_rec(players, num_of_rounds):
    games_map = {}
    next_players = []

    assert len(players) > 0

    if len(players) == 1:
        return games_map

    gm=1
    for i in range(int(len(players) / 2)):
        player1_id = i
        player2_id = len(players) - 1 - i

        if players[player2_id] is None:
            next_players.append(players[player1_id])
        else:
            round=str(1+num_of_rounds-int(math.log(len(players), 2)))
            game_id = "round_"+round + "_game_" + str(gm)#str(i + 1)
            g = Game((players[player1_id], players[player2_id]), game_id)
            g.round, g.game = round, gm
            games_map[g.id] = g#{'players':g.players, 'winner':g.winner, 'loser':g.loser, 'done':g.done}
            # next_players.append((g, "winner"))  #the winner of that game
            # next_players.append('winner of %s and %s' % (g.players))
            next_players.append('winner of Round %s Game %s' % (g.round, g.game))

            gm += 1
    d = {}
    d.update(games_map)
    d.update(generate_bracket_rec(next_players, num_of_rounds).items())
    return d
```

**Errors in formatting**

I have tried different ways of dealing with the JSON tournament object, as it stands now the error I have is happening in js in $.post - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, so code is not even reaching the update_bracket view.

DevTools shows

```
$.post('/update_bracket',
        { bracketData: JSON.stringify("{&#x27;round_1_game_1&#x27;: round_1_game_1: 2 vs 3
Done: False, &#x27;round_2_game_1&#x27;: round_2_game_1: 1 vs winner of Round 1 Game 1
Done: False}") },
```

Does anyone know how I need to be dealing with this tournament object in the lifecycle

python (generated as dict)-->template (passed in as context var) -->python (from .post of that passed-in-template-var)-->save to django JSONField-->retrieved from JSONField (restart of cycle)

**EDIT - JSON Decode error**

After following advice of what to do with the passing-to-template, I get a new error in update_bracket. I am able to send the data there, but then when I try to loads() it I get JSONDecode error. Do you know how I can deal with this?

```
request.POST['bracketData']
'{&quot;round_1_game_1&quot;: {&quot;players&quot;: [2, 3], &quot;winner&quot;: null, &quot;loser&quot;: null, &quot;done&quot;: false}, &quot;round_2_game_1&quot;: {&quot;players&quot;: [1, &quot;winner of Round 1 Game 1&quot;], &quot;winner&quot;: null, &quot;loser&quot;: null, &quot;done&quot;: false}}'
json.loads(request.POST['bracketData'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: `{{ arr }}` is printing the python object `tournament_games`, which I think is a dictionary. You shouldn't print it in your template like this, that becomes a string that isn't in json format (and JSON.stringify() javascript function works for a javascript object, not for a string). You just need to print it as json string in python: so in your context `'arr': json.dumps(tournament_games)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `{{ arr }}` in your template, you're just telling python to print the `arr` object as string. Since `arr` is a dictionary (it's `tournament_games`), you're printing something like `{'key': 'value'}` which isn't a JSON string (JSON strings need double-quotes `"`).

And then you wrap it in `""` making it a javascript string and your javascript calls `JSON.stringify()` on it. But that doesn't work, because `stringify()` expects a javascript object, not a string.

Since all you want is post a JSON string, create that string in python and print that in your template. In your context:

```
'arr': json.dumps(tournament_games)
```

and in your template:

```
bracketData: "{{ arr }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this has made some progress for me, but I am running into another hiccup trying to loads that JSON (I provide the passed in JSON and also the JSONDecodeError I get. Thanks for help so far, wondering if you could explain that as well?